# Search coding in php

Tags: php, mysql

I had an error while compile this code.. Can somebody help me?

search.html

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="search0.php">
                Search by Matric No.:
                <input type="text" name="patron_ID" placeholder="Student No.">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
          </form>
```

search0.php

```
<?php
/* include db connection file*/
include("dbconnect.php");

/* capture student number */
//$idsaja = $_POST['idsaja'];
$patron_ID = $_POST['patron_ID'];

/* execute SQL statement */
$sql= " SELECT br.patron_ID, p.patron_Name, br.book_Accession, b.book_Title, br.borrowed_Date,
                    br.discharged_Date, br.due_Date, b.book_Status

                    FROM borrow br
                    INNER JOIN patrons p 
                    ON p.patron_ID = br.patron_ID
                    JOIN book b
                    ON b.book_Accession = br.book_Accession
                    WHERE patron_ID = '$patron_ID'";

//"SELECT * FROM patrons WHERE patron_ID= '$patron_ID'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($row == 0){
echo "No record found";
}
else{
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$patron_ID = $r['patron_ID'];
$patron_Name = $r['patron_Name'];
$book_Accession = $r['book_Accession'];
$book_Title = $r['book_Title'];
$borrowed_Date = $r['borrowed_Date'];
$discharged_Date = $r['discharged_Date'];
$due_Date = $r['due_Date'];
$book_Status = $r['book_Status'];
?>
```

The error is "Error: Column 'patron_ID' in where clause is ambiguous".. What that mean? Can someone explain to me..

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: try to add `WHERE br.patron_ID`, consider using mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: you just need to add the table to it, like the other ones `WHERE p.patron_ID`

Answer (score 3):

I think the message is self-explanatory.

Your SQL is querying multiple tables: I see `borrow` and `patrons`. Both of these tables contain a column called `patron_ID`, and MySQL doesn't know if you're referring to `borrow.patron_ID` or `patrons.patron_ID` (the fact that there's a Foreign Key relationship doesn't help MySQL).

You need to disambiguate the query by providing the full column name by prefixing it with the table name - you may use either the full name or its alias.

Answer (score 0):

You surely have another patron_ID in other(s) table(s), prefix your column in the where clause "p.patron_ID"

Answer (score 0):

I miss something..The code should be like this :

```
$sql= " SELECT br.patron_ID, p.patron_Name, br.book_Accession, b.book_Title, br.borrowed_Date,
                    br.discharged_Date, br.due_Date, b.book_Status

                    FROM borrow br
                    INNER JOIN patrons p 
                    ON p.patron_ID = br.patron_ID
                    JOIN book b
                    ON b.book_Accession = br.book_Accession
                    **WHERE br.patron_ID = '$patron_ID'";**
```

My error is solved.. Thank you all :)